# Background Images not showing after deployment

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

I'm using Nextjs and Tailwind for the css. I deployed to vercel since it's optimized for Nextjs but my background images are not showing after deployment.

The repo: https://github.com/Dayropo/tkbrown
The site: https://tkbrown-6di53m6xz-dayropo.vercel.app

When I checked the developer tools I saw this

> .bg-swirl {
> background-image: url(webpack:///mini-css-extract-plugin/_next/static/media/swirl_t1.8b530f8a.png)
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `tailwind.config.json` to these:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        playfair: "Playfair Display, serif",
        hind: "Hind, sans-serif",
        poppins: "Poppins, sans-serif",
        oswald: "Oswald, sans-serif",
      },
      fontSize: {
        "4.5xl": "2.5rem",
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        swirl: "url('/swirl_t1.png')",
        about: "url('/about-background.png')",
        aboutCloud:
          "url('https://res.cloudinary.com/dayropo/image/upload/v1650049471/about-background_zhkq9b.png')",
      },
      colors: {
        modal: "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.9)",
        gravy: "#FFFFFF80",
        opa: "rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
        dark: "#777777",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

background-image: url('') should has `'` or `"`